# ImageView - Unwanted padding at left and right

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have an ImageView inside a ScrollView. The width and height of the ImageView and match_parent and wrap_content. But, the ImageView has slight padding on the left and right to it. The image is downloaded from server and shown in the ImageView.

Here is my XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.xx.xxx"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar_without_spinner" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_select_activity"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/green"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/ll_feature"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/text_layout"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                    android:paddingTop="10dp"
                    android:visibility="gone" >

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/item_features_title"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/empty"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/item_features_description"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/empty"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >
                    <!-- ImageView with the problem -->
                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/item_features_imageview_icon"
                        android:layout_width="0dip"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:padding="0dp"
                        android:contentDescription="@string/item_features_icon"
                        android:cropToPadding="false"
                        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

           ....
           .... 
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Please find the screenshots below:

[image]

[image]

How do i make the ImageView match the total width of the scrollView and also maintain the aspect ratio?

Shouldn't "fitCenter" automatically match the edges, as per documentation?

ImageView.ScaleType. FIT_CENTER

> Compute a scale that will maintain the original src aspect ratio, but
>   will also ensure that src fits entirely inside dst. At least one axis
>   (X or Y) will fit exactly. The result is centered inside dst.

Comment: try changing `android:scaleType="fitCenter"`  to `android:scaleType="fitXY" `

Comment: ok.. But, will fitXY maintains "aspect ratio" of the image downloaded? I want to maintain the aspect ratio because i don't want the image to stretch or squeeze

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

```
android:scaleType="fitX"
```

It will expand your image in horizontal removing the extra padding

You can also use

```
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

It will expand both in vertical as well as horizontal

Comment: Well though i wanted to go only with fitCenter conceptually, fitXY did the work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`android:scaleType="fitX"` It will expand your image in horizontal removing the extra padding `android:scaleType="fitXY"` It will expand both in vertical as well as horizontal

use `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` when you have large image Its djust bounds to preserve the aspect ratio of its drawable.

**`Ex.`**

```
<ImageView
      android:scaleType="fitXY"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:adjustViewBounds="true"
      app:srcCompat="@drawable/background_design" />
```